# After save my data, one object return from memory not fetching from database,

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I am using Spring JPA for my database. After the updating data in the database, fetching all data from the database, but one record which I have updated that record return from memory.

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class DepartmentController {
@PutMapping("${service.deptupdate.url}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Update existing department by deptId and clientId", response = Boolean.class)
    public ResponseEntity<List<DepartmentDTO>> updateDept(@RequestBody DepartmentDTO deptDTO)
            throws DepartmentException {
        log.info("DepartmentController : updateDept: saving the department {} for {} client", deptDTO.getDeptId(),
                deptDTO.getClientId());
        deptDTO = departmentService.saveOrUpdateDept(deptDTO);
        log.info("DepartmentController : updateDept: Successfully updated department {} for clinet{}",
                deptDTO.getDeptId(), deptDTO.getClientId()); 

        return new ResponseEntity<List<DepartmentDTO>>(departmentService.findAllDepartment(deptDTO.getClientId()),
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**Service**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DepartmentServiceImpl implements DepartmentService {
@Override
    public DepartmentDTO saveOrUpdateDept(DepartmentDTO deptDTO) {
        log.info("Saving department for clientId{}", deptDTO.getClinicId());
        Department dept = DepartmentUtils.deptDetailsDTOTOEntity(deptDTO);
        dept = departmentRepository.saveAndFlush(dept);
        DepartmentDTO departmentDTO = DepartmentUtils.deptDetailsEntityTODTO(dept);
        if(null != departmentDTO.getDeptId())
        log.info("Successfully save/update department {} for client{}", departmentDTO.getDeptId()+":"+departmentDTO.getDeptName(), departmentDTO.getClientId());
        return departmentDTO;
    }

@Override
    public List<DepartmentDTO> findAllDepartment(Long clientId) {
        log.info("Getting all department list for clientId{}", clientId);
        List<Department> deptList = departmentRepository.findByClientId(clientId);
        List<DepartmentDTO> deptDTOList = DepartmentUtils.deptDetailsEntityTODTOList(deptList);
        log.info("Found {} department list for clientId{}", deptDTOList.size(), clientId);
        return deptDTOList;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long>{
          public List<Department> findByClientId(@Param("cliId")Long clientId);
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
@DynamicUpdate(true)
@DynamicInsert(true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Department implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPT_ID", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long deptId;

    @Column(name = "CLIENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long clientId;

    @Column(name = "DEPT_NAME")
    private String deptName;

    @Column(name = "DEPT_CODE")
    private String deptCode;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private Boolean status;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String createdBy;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "CREATED_TIME", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdTime;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
    private String updatedBy;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_TIME", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime updatedTime;

}
```

Below is the my database configuration in yml file

```
# Database Configuration    
spring:
   application:
      name: eclinic-queue-management
   profile:
      active: local   
   datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/client?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      username: root
      password: *****
      driver.class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   jpa:
      show-sql: true
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
      hibernate.format_sql: true
      hibernate.ddl-auto: none
```

Updating below data via RESTAPI - Request

```
{
    "deptId": 1,
    "clientId" : 2,
    "deptName" : "General",
    "deptCode" : "GGG",
    "status": true,
    "createdBy": "GULAB",
    "updatedBy": "GULAB"
}
```

Response return from database

```
[
    {
        "deptId": 1,
        "clinicId": 2,
        "deptName": "General",
        "deptCode": "GGG",
        "deptDoctorId": "6",
        "tokenStartWith": "GGG",
        "status": true,
        "createdBy": "GULAB", // <-- this is not the value from the database
        "createdTime": null,  // <-- this is not the value from the database

        "updatedBy": "GULAB",
        "updatedTime": "2020-04-02T22:21:11.352"
    },
    {
        "deptId": 2,
        "clinicId": 2,
        "deptName": "General",
        "deptCode": "GEN",
        "deptDoctorId": "3",
        "tokenStartWith": "G",
        "status": true,
        "createdBy": "Jayesh",
        "createdTime": "2020-03-27T12:42:50.076",
        "updatedBy": "Jayesh",
        "updatedTime": "2020-03-27T12:42:50.077"
    }
]
```

But in database  `createdBy` value is `Jayesh` and `createdTime` is not `null`

I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: I formatted and slightly edited your question. Please make sure I didn't change the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You mapped both `createdBy` and `createdTime` with `updatable = false` so they don't get updated in the database.

On the other hand the entities are stored in the `EntityManager` therefore they don't get reloaded by JPA as by the JPA guarantee that an entity with given class and id must only exist once in a session.

If you want to reload entities from the database evict them from the session or use a fresh `EntityManger`, i.e. execute it in a new transaction

Comment: Thank you Jens for a quick response.
The first one I can understand, it will not update but must get fresh value from a database.

How to call fresh `EnitryManager`.  I tried below but didn't work.

`@Transactional
 public List<Department> findByClientId(@Param("cliId")Long clientId);`

Comment: Thanks again Jens, still having the same issue.

`
@Override
 **@Transactional
 @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)**
 public DepartmentDTO saveOrUpdateDept(DepartmentDTO deptDTO) {
 
 }
`
Also added on mail class

`
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class MainApplication {
}
`